# Image crop functionality not working properly when using jcrop plugin

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting an issue while using `jcrop` plugin, I displayed image in bootstrap model and give fixed width and height (500,333).
In this model when I tried to crop image it selects ratio according to current height and width but crop the image according to original dimension of image i.e (1500 , 1000).
If I select image of (500,333) dimensions then it works perfectly.
please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution for my above problem and it works for me:

```
$('.crop').Jcrop({
            boxWidth: boxWidth,
            onSelect: showCoords,
            onChange: showCoords,
            trueSize : [1500,1000],
            bgColor:     'black',
            bgOpacity:   0.3,
            aspectRatio: 1
       });
```

provide true size of image means image's original width and height then it scales perfectly.